# Find the first p tag value of a div with jquery? (Next.js + Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, next.js

Im trying to find the value of the first `<p>` tag inside my div when i click a button inside the same div.
Note: The `$(this)` doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```jsx
<div className="cartcontainer">
  <p
    key={item.id}
    style={{
      display: "inline-block",
      marginTop: "auto",
      marginBottom: "auto",
      float: "left",
    }}
  >
    NFT ID: {item.id}
  </p>
  <p
    key={item.id}
    style={{
      display: "inline-block",
      marginTop: "auto",
      marginBottom: "auto",
      float: "left",
    }}
  >
    Price: {item.price}
  </p>
  <button
    style={{
      float: "right",
      width: 40,
      height: 40,
      fontSize: 20,
      borderRadius: 12,
      display: "block",
    }}
    onClick={() => removeCartItemHandler(cart.findIndex($(this).closest("p")))}
  >
    X
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd strongly advise against using jQuery within a React / Next app.

Comment: _"Im trying to find the value of the first `<p>` tag"_... what do you mean by _value_? `<p>` tags don't have any `value` property. Did you mean the text content or some other attribute?

Comment: Use `.find` instead of `.closest`

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has no place within a React project. The former operates on the DOM directly whereas the latter uses state to drive the display.

Instead of trying to access a known value from a  previous element, just use the known value

```jsx
<button
  type="button"
  style={{
    float: "right",
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    fontSize: 20,
    borderRadius: 12,
    display: "block",
  }}
  onClick={() => removeCartItemHandler(cart.findIndex(`NFT ID: ${item.id}`))}
>
  X
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div className="cartcontainer">
  <p>
    NFT ID: 1
  </p>
  <p>
    Price: 23
  </p>
  <button
    onclick="removeCartItemHandler(this)"
  >
    X
  </button>
</div>
<script>
  function removeCartItemHandler(e){
    console.log($(e).siblings("p")[0]);
  }
</script>
```

JQuery has a method called siblings where you can find all the nodes associated with the same parent class. You can pass class name, id, and selector to fetch a particular element. as it returns an array, you can fetch the first element via indexing.

Answer (score -2):

simple one-liner, self-explanitory:

```js
$( ".cartcontainer p:first-child" ).text();
```

Comment: This will select the first `<p>` tag in **every** `.cartcontainer` and then return the text from the very first one. It does not take into account the clicked element at all

Comment: Copied and pasted from the web, not experienced in jq at all.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.